# How to a Make Component by artisan command without class?

Tags: php, view, components, laravel-8, laravel-artisan

I want to make a component in Laravel 8 by this command: php artisan make:component forms.input --view that means  i want a component with only a Blade template and no class.
But i m Getting this ERROR: The "--view" option does not exist.  Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 1):

well, you may create a sub-directory under components let's say `...components/buttons`.
Then just create a blade file representing your component for example `round.blade.php`.
use this component in any template like so `<x-buttons.round />` and your component will be rendered correctly in your template.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a components folder, I would suggest making that first. Generally, I usually put mine under `resources/views/components`.

Then if you want to create a view for your component without a class, you can use this command:

```
php artisan make:component COMPONENT_NAME --view
```

This is on Laravel 10